# What is _SERVER["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]

Tags: php

`phpinfo()` shows a variable named `_SERVER["CONTEXT_PREFIX"]`. It is not documented at http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php.
What exactly is it? Where can I find documentation on all of the `$_SERVER[*]` variables? There are a few more in that list that are not on the php.net webpage.

**EDIT**
I see from the comments that this is probably server-dependent. I am using the UniServer stack on windows, but since this is unreliable, I won't depend in this key being present.

Is there a list of which keys are present 99% of the time (that is, in all likely setups)?

Comment: Are you using a framework or CMS? That's definitely no default PHP key.

Comment: That probably means it's set by the web server or an extension. It would help if you could provide more information about those.

Comment: "The entries in this array are created by the web server. There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; **servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here.**" I don't think you can find documentation of **ALL** the `$_SERVER[*]` variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like it's new in Apache 2.3.13, according to source control for June 28th. There is also CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT which appears easier to understand.

"Introduce new context_document_root and context_prefix which provide information about non-global URI-to-directory mappings (from e.g. mod_userdir or mod_alias) to scripts." Source: http://marc.info/?l=apache-cvs&m=130928191414740

It's coming from Apache, and is related to when you can have different mappings between the request URI and different directories, such as when you use http://example.com/~username to access a website under "username"'s web space, so the actual document root will vary.

I presume where it will come in useful is if you specify multiple directory sources for one URI, such as:

```
Userdir public_html /usr/web
```

then you're never sure if the files are at "public_html" or "/usr/web" (as it tries one first, then the other) so the CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT and CONTEXT_PREFIX help you find it.

Can't see any formal documentation on it yet as 2.3 appears to have been skipped in the docs (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/)

---

Edit: The comments have answered your other part about what server variables can you rely on (impossible to say). If you find that the "CONTEXT" variables are meeting your needs, then you may need to write a functions that says "if they exist, use them, but if not, use another one".

A common example of this is when you try to (unreliably, I know) get the source protocol. You'll check for the proxy added headers first (X_FORWARDED_PROTO) before you search for HTTPS = 'on'. You may need to do similar if the environment variable just happens to be right on your server.

Comment: Adding a comment that this also appears in the release notes for 2.4 (http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/CHANGES_2.4). But still nothing in the 2.4 documentation.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a default PHP key for the $_SERVER global.

You can take a look at the PHP manual for the `$_SERVER` global variable:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

EDIT: (Pay attention to the bolded sentence)

> $_SERVER is an array containing information such as headers, paths,
>   and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web
>   server. There is **no guarantee that every web server will provide any
>   of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here.**
>   That said, a large number of these variables are accounted for in the
>   » CGI/1.1 specification, so you should be able to expect those.